# Income reported on W2 was not received AND the company no longer exists

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, form-w-2

Our situation is the same as in [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/20541/received-w-2-but-was-never-paid):

- Spouse was employed by the company till Jan 31 '17, but was on unpaid leave for the entire month so no salary.
- We now receive a W2 for 1 month's wages but there was no check/direct deposit corresponding to that amount (or any amount) for that month.

**The additional twist here is that the company no longer exists** — they closed operations sometime fall '17. We do not have a person to contact at the company, since all employees were laid off. Further more, we're not sure if this money somehow represents legitimate backpay/corrections/bonuses for 2016 that were paid out in 2017 and it was just a human error that the check went missing or wasn't sent out.

How should we go about correcting this? We could take it straight to the IRS, but unclear if we can have ambiguity in not knowing whether it was actually $0 in wages or a case of missing check.

Comment: Contact the IRS.  The company may not exist, but the founders do and they can and will be held responsible.

Comment: The fact that the company is now closed makes it sufficiently non-duplicate, IMO.

Comment: @PeteB. answering in comments is strongly discouraged...

Comment: @MD-Tech agree.  However, since this is a duplicate question, I just wanted to address the OP's chief concern that the company does not exist.  That does not matter in the IRS's eyes.